# Location of the setting file of indicator-multiload

Tags: configuration

Where the setting file of [indicator-multiload](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) exists?

It is needed to backup and restore the preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting is stored in [dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf).

To backup, run the following command:

```
dconf dump /de/mh21/indicator-multiload/ > ./backup
```

And to restore it, run the following:

```
dconf load /de/mh21/indicator-multiload/ < ./backup
```